# How to make it so I can use the data from App.Config

Tags: c#, app-config

I've written this so far but I can seem to get it so the Operator command right. I want to write it so when it is between Monday and Friday Excecute said code.

```
DayOfWeek day = DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek;
            TimeSpan now = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
            string FromDate = string.Empty;
            TimeSpan FromTime = new TimeSpan();
            TimeSpan ToTime = new TimeSpan();

            foreach (var key in applicationSettings.AllKeys)
            {
                if (key == "FromDate")
                {
                  FromDate = applicationSettings[key];
                }

if ((day >= FromDate) && (now > FromTime) && (now < ToTime))
{
    // execute code here
}
```

I cannot get the FromDate to work properly. FromTime, ToTime is 8:00 AM and 17:00.

Comment: check to see what the value of `key` is on every run, its most likely `FromDate` isn't being set

Comment: For sure It being set as a Monday. And the key is also monday

Comment: if `key` is "Monday" then `FromDate` wont be set as "Monday"!="FromDate"

Comment: I know that is the problem. in app.config it is set as Monday in key FromDate. But I get the error "operator '>=' cannot be applied to opreands of type 'Systems.DayOfWeek' and 'string'

Comment: day is an enum. you are comparing enum with string? Either convert your day to show monday/Tuesday/ or whatever or convert your fromDate string to Enum of type DayOfWeek

Comment: well no you cant compare a dayofweek and a string you will need to convert to a string

Comment: if `day` and `FromDate` are both of type `string` you wont get that error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the  *"between Monday and Friday"* part of your question:
The [DayOfWeek](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dayofweek.aspx) Is an enum representation of the week Starting at Sunday to Saturday.

You can store it in your config, the index may be the easiest way to represent those day:

```
<add key="FromDay" value="1" /> <!--Monday-->
<add key="ToDay" value="5" />   <!--Friday-->
```

Now a simple cast and comparaison will give you result you need:

```
var confRead = new System.Configuration.AppSettingsReader();
var fromDay= (int)confRead.GetValue("FromDay", typeof(int));            
var toDay = (int)confRead.GetValue("ToDay", typeof(int));

var result = IsValidDay(DateTime.Now, fromDay, toDay);

private bool IsValidDay(DateTime day, int fromDay = 1, int toDay = 5)
{
    var testDay = (int)day.DayOfWeek;
    return (fromDay > testDay && testDay > toDay);
}
```

You can now apply the same logic to find if we are between 08:00 and 17:00. Using TimeSpan and 'TimeOfDay'

Answer (score 0):

This can be considered as a way. Might not be really efficient. But can be considered.
You can probably add a new variable and convert your FromDate to enum and save it there.

```
            DayOfWeek FromDateEnum;

           if (key == "FromDate")
            {
              FromDate = applicationSettings[key];
              Enum.TryParse<DayOfWeek>(FromDate, out FromDateEnum);
            }
```

and change your if condition to use enum rather than string

```
          if ((day >= FromDateEnum ) && (now > FromTime) && (now < ToTime))
            {
                // execute code here
            }
```

and in addition to that you can easily manage using FromDateEnum  to compare with DayOfWeek Enum values.